# Upload Folder via Mac Terminal

Tags: macos

How can I upload an entire folder via FTP Mac Terminal?

Answer (score 27):

Do you have to use `ftp`? I like to use `scp` (secure copy) when the remote host supports ssh (as so many of them do).

`scp -r mydirectory username@example.com:destdir`

The `-r` means "recursive" so it will recursively copy the entire directory.  Replace `username` with your username, etc., etc.  `destdir` is a relative path on the remote server (whatever directory you wind up in if you log in) as long as you don't use a leading slash `/` -- then it will be an absolute path.

Comment: Why offer this answer.. he asks for FTP! reasons to use FTP DO exists... no matter if I like scp better... which I actually do

Comment: @ksthor Good point, but this was the answer I was looking for when I googled "upload entire folder ssh" :)

Comment: Because it is a great resource for other people searching for solutions on **similar** matter. Yes, even in 2017, @kasthor.

Comment: The right answer is given by DEAD10CC and is to use ncftpput

Comment: It's good to revisit answers as times change. I don't think `homebrew` was around 6 years ago so it can be easier to obtain tools that don't come preinstalled like `ssh`/`scp`. Regardless, I sure hope everyone has moved beyond using plaintext FTP across public AND private networks.

Answer (score 17):

```
    terminal>ftp user@host
     password:xXxXx
    ftp>mkdir <remote dir>
    ftp>cd <remote dir>
    ftp>lcd <local dir>
    ftp>mput *
    ftp>close
```

This will

- connect
- create the remote directory (or folder)
- cd into that directory
- cd to the local directory (if you didn't start there
- copy multiple files (all)
- log out again

[see the man page online](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ftp)

Comment: Worked great for me! Thanks! The one thing I'd change is that I'd use `sftp` instead. Same commands, just where it says `ftp` use `sftp`. It's much more secure.

Comment: `mput -r *` is needed for recursive copying

Comment: ftp was removed from mac since high sierra. the above works, but FTP needs to be installed: https://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0001364

Answer (score 13):

mput is the right command for that task, but I think OS X' implementation of ftp command line client does not support recursive copy of directories via mput *.

So, a possible solution might be the use of an alternative ftp command line client like NcFTP that is shipped with many linux distributions and is also available for OS X. See [NcFTP download page](http://www.ncftp.com/download/) for details.

```
ncftpput -R -u user -p passwd <remote-host> <remote-dir> <local-dir>
```

The `-R` is for recursive mode.

Comment: Thank you @Joker for the NcFTP recommendation. This worked perfectly for my needs. I was able to transfer an entire directory, and it's elegant to have a one-liner in script files.

Comment: To install ncftp on a mac these days, you can `brew install ncftp` (assuming you have homebrew, which you probably should)

Comment: this is the best solution... should be the answer of the question as it does the job in one line of code.

Answer (score 1):

Same as you would upload an entire folder from any other command line:

1. Make a zip or tar archive out of it,
   then put the archive.
2. If you want to
   upload individual files, but do them
   all, use "mput".

Answer (score 0):

have you tried mput?  You can pass it A wildcard (*) to upload all the files...

Comment: I put in "put *foldername" and I get "foldername: not a plain file."

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some question as to whether ftp through the mac is capable of handling recursive copy.
If you have ssh access to both machines, you could do this from the source computer:
tar -cf - directory | ssh user@hostB "cd target_dir; tar -xf -"

mput * should work fine for objects within the directory, but if you have subdirectories, it may have problems picking up the files.

Answer (score 0):

Go - Connect To Server.   Enter ftp://ip-address-of-other-box and appropriate credentials.  Click + to add that server, then double-click on it to open it.   You can now drag and drop folders and it will copy recursively.

Comment: This works great for me... but only read-only, for some reason.  Won't let me upload anything.

Comment: He asked on how to do it with the Terminal.